# NetBeans 10 Blurry when JDK 11 is Installed?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-11, blurry, netbeans-10

When I originally installed Apache NetBeans 10 I was using JDK 8 (1.8.0_201) and the GUI looked fine.

[Loading Menu fine with JDK 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBZNN.png)

[IDE fine with JDK 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeVKY.png)

I got NetBeans 10 for the purpose of working with Java 11, **however after installing JDK 11 (11.0.2), the NetBeans GUI became bigger and blurry, and I don't know why?**

[Loading Menu Bigger and Blurry with JDK 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBxhg.png)

[IDE buttons and images blurry with JDK 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfcD6.png)

*I will also note that this also happens with my swing programs I was developing in Java, once Java JDK 11 was installed all the buttons in the programs became bigger, and the images became blurry.*

Comment: I recommend reading [JDK-8055212/JEP 263: HiDPI Graphics on Windows and Linux](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055212). Now that AWT/Swing is doing it right, every application rolling its own “poor man’s double buffering” using a `BufferedImage` or such alike will look bad when not considering the difference between the logical size (as reported by `Component.getSize()`) and the pixel size (which you get when applying `component.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDefaultTransform()` to the size).

Comment: I'm experiencing exact same behaviour.